# How do I remove an event listener that has been passed in as an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, events

While adding an event listener to an object, I have to pass in an argument to my function, so therefore, must wrap it like so `el.addEventListener("click", (evt) => { someFunc(arg) })`. However, I am unable to remove this event listener later on in my project. How do you remove an event listener when the function that is being referenced is an anonymous function?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). This **requires** that you keep a reference to your function about.

```
var func = (evt) => { someFunc(arg) };
el.addEventListener("click", func);
el.removeEventListener("click", func)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `addOneTimeEventListener` function, using [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), to later use it throughout your project with multiple types of events:

```
function addOneTimeEventListener(node, type, callback) {
    node.addEventListener(type, function(evt) {
        evt.target.removeEventListener(evt.type, arguments.callee);
        return callback(evt);
    });
}
```

And than use it:

```
addOneTimeEventListener(el, 'click', evt => someFunc(arg));
```

Working demo:

```js
var addOneTimeEventListener = function(node, type, callback) {
      node.addEventListener(type, function(evt) {
        evt.target.removeEventListener(evt.type, arguments.callee);
        return callback(evt);
      });
    },
    el = document.getElementById('paragraph');

addOneTimeEventListener(el, 'click', evt => console.log('Clicked once!'));
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Some text example...</p>
```

Comment: Whenever I attempt to invoke the function, I get an error that `el.addOneTimeEventListener is not a function`. I seem to be implementing an identical function, any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: I have edited the solution and added a working demo.. Hope it helps